# Jquery is not replacing URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

My problem is rather simple however I cannot make it to work, on localhost it is replacing the href without any problems however on a server it doesn't and I don't know if it's because of .htaccess file changing the URL and that's why Jquery doesn't change it or there is something wrong with this code.

The href is retrieved from screen scrape and it contains second half of url so something like:

> /some/content

and it looks like

> http://dev.website1/some/content

while it should look like:

> http://www.google.co.uk/some/content

```
var base = "http://www.google.co.uk/";
$('a').each(function(index, element) {
  element.href = element.href.replace("http://dev.website1/", base);
});
$('img').each(function(index, element) {
  element.src = element.src.replace("http://dev.website1/", base);
});
```

Comment: `http://dev.website1/` isn't in the string you are replacing.

Comment: What am I replacing if on localhost it works fine but instead of dev.website I have localhost

Comment: Right. `<a href="/foo/bar.php">` points to `http://localhost/foo/bar.php`. the href value is `/foo/bar.php`. what is confusing about that?

Comment: Check out my last change!

Answer (score 0):

You should set the elements `.prop([prop])` or `.attr([attr])`, instead of `.href` / `.src`.

```js
var base = "http://www.google.co.uk/";

$('a').each(function() {
  var $element = $(this);
  var href = $element.prop('href');

  $element.prop('href', href.replace("http://dev.website1/", base));
});

$('img').each(function() {
  var $element = $(this);
  var src = $element.prop('src');

  $element.prop('src', src.replace("http://dev.website1/", base));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a href="http://dev.website1/test_href">Test href</a><br />
  <a href="http://dev.website1/test_href2">Test href2</a><br />
  <a href="http://dev.website1/test_href3">Test href3</a><br />
</div>
<br />
<div>
  <img src="http://dev.website1/test_src.png" alt="test_src" /><br />
  <img src="http://dev.website1/test_src2.png" alt="test_src2" /><br />
  <img src="http://dev.website1/test_src3.png" alt="test_src3" /><br />
</div>
```

Comment: you see here it works but on mine, it doesn't change. is it because of .htaccess and it's rewrite rule? it looks like it is not forcing it to change

Comment: You should _always_ use `.prop()`, but if it doesn't work, try using `.attr()` instead. If it still doesn't work, check the dev console on the browser.

Comment: both of those didn't work. What should I look for in the console?

Comment: For javascript errors or something. Also, you could try debugging. Add `debugger;` to any line you wish to stop and run the page with the console opened.

Comment: @Przemek, did you find the reason?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var base = "http://www.google.co.uk/";
    $('a').each(function(index, element) {
      let e1 = $(element)
      e1.attr('href', e1.attr('href').replace("http://dev.website1/", base));
    });
    $('img').each(function(index, element) {
      let e1 = $(element)
      e1.attr('src', e1.attr('src').replace("http://dev.website1/", base));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="http://dev.website1/aaa">link1</a>
<img src="http://dev.website1/bbb" />
```

try this snippet... using `.attr()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```js
var base = "http://www.google.co.uk/";
$('a').each(function(index, element) {
  $(element).attr('href').replace("http://dev.website1/", base);
});
$('img').each(function(index, element) {
  $(element).attr('src').replace("http://dev.website1/", base);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://dev.website1/">Test</a>
<img src="http://dev.website1/"">
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work. is it because I have rewrite rule in .htaccess?

Answer (score -1):

element.href might not be supported on all browsers. Try fetching it using element.getAttribute('href').

Comment: UXDart's solution is pretty good. You should be setting the href as an attribute using jQuery's attr method.